# PHP cURL / Построить запрос из текстового представления

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Есть ли возможность без парсинга сгенерировать CURL запрос из строки как в консоли?

Есть строка

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://sandbox.com/test' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"ids":[{"id":263214}]}'
```

Которую просто передаем через форму, а скрипт выполнит запрос и вернет данные для проверки?

Я уже начал вспоминать как разобрать этот текст и дабы сделать запрос (много лет не практикую), но вот решил спросить у знатоков, может есть что-то проще)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://sandbox.com/test';
$params['ids'][] = ['id'=>263214];
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' =>  http_build_query($params),
    )
)));
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если только эту стороку "как есть" выполнять как внешнюю программу через exec или  аналогичную функцию, а результат выполнения возвращать пользователю. В общем-то, по идее, должно работать.